# What is the correct way to implement a GridViewPager on Android Wear?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view, wear-os

I'm trying to implement a GridViewPager so I can switch between 2 unique views. So far I haven't been able to add any views at all. Below is my code

```
public class Gridder extends Activity {

private TextView mTextView;
GridViewPager gridViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridder);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            gridViewPager = (GridViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            gridViewPager.setAdapter(new MyGridViewPagerAdapter());
            gridViewPager.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_generic, stub));;
        }
    });
}

private class MyGridViewPagerAdapter extends GridPagerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void destroyItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, int arg2, Object arg3) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(int arg0) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the rectangle child of the main view stub, I have a GridViewPager with the id pager, exactly as I referenced above:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true" />
```

This code throws an illegal state exception and reports that my child view already has a parent. See below

```
07-16 14:44:40.847  12940-12940/com.larvalabs.weartest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.larvalabs.weartest, PID: 12940
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3561)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3414)
        at android.support.wearable.view.GridViewPager.addView(GridViewPager.java:1088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3359)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3335)
        at com.larvalabs.weartest.Gridder$1.onLayoutInflated(Gridder.java:30)
        at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:133)
        at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onMeasure(WatchViewStub.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2321)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1145)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1340)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1032)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Stacktrace explanation:

First of all - the following line is wrong:

```
gridViewPager.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_generic, stub));
```

`inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)`
with `root!=null` is the same as
 `inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`
with last argument as `true`.

So according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean)) it will inflate view from `resource` and attach it to root -> then return a root.

this will try to attach newly inflated view to `stub`, and then try to attach `stub` (result from `inflate()` with specified `root`) to the `gridViewPager`. But `stub` already has a parent (it's already attached to the view hierarchy in your activity). So this is an explanation of stacktrace:)
Please note that you should NOT add views to `gridViewPager` via `.addView()` methods - you should do it via adapter instead and that line should be removed.

### GridPagerAdapter example:

Here is simple implementation for `GridPagerAdapter`;

```
private class MyGridViewPagerAdapter extends GridPagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount(int arg0) {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int row, int col) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_view_pager_item, container, false);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(String.format("Page:\n%1$s, %2$s", row, col));
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int row, int col, Object view) {
        container.removeView((View)view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }
}
```

Content of `grid_view_pager_item.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#4400ff00"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="26sp"/> 

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is a final result of 2x2 grid. Two screens are in still state and two are pictured during the pages being half-scrolled:)

[image]

---

### Looking for more?

This is just an example of using standard `GridPagerAdapter`. If you want more advanced one, with usage of `FragmentGridPagerAdapter`, `CardFragments` and pages backgrounds - please see the `GridViewPager` example located in platform samples:
`{sdk_root}/samples/android-20/wearable/GridViewPager`

Comment: Is it possible to add page indicator in GridViewPager?

Comment: There is setOnPageChanngedListener which could be used to implement this.

Comment: Maciej Ciemięga, thanks for this it is a really good example, I have one problem when I add a background though, 

    @Override
    public ImageReference getBackground(int row, int column) {
        // default, if nothing else
        return ImageReference.forDrawable(R.drawable.debug_background_1);
    }

As I swipe up and down there is an annoying white flash, is there anything that can be done about this?

Comment: There is now a DotsPageIndicator included with the library. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/DotsPageIndicator.html